# Is there a way to change asyncio.sleep while currently sleeping?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-asyncio

If I have a coroutine currently sleeping to allow other coroutines to run, is is possible to change the sleep time while sleeping? Or would I have to cancel and restart the coroutine. I think I may have just answered myself there. Looking for help from the more experienced.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 2):

The "sleep" coroutine is obviously designed to be simple: it pauses for that amount of time, and it is it.

What you seem to need is a way to synchronize your co-routines, and if no signal gets back in an specified amount of time (the time you are passing to sleep), to move on.

Take a look at the synchronization primitives https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-sync.html and [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for)

So, you can instead of asyncio.sleep, call a co-routine, with wait_for, where it expects an Event, or a Lock release. The Event or lock-release then is used by whatever part of your code would "cancel sleep" anyway.

I created an example to show both sleeping running to the end, and being canceled.

```
import asyncio

async def interruptable_sleep(time, event):
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=time)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("'sleeping' proceeded normaly")
    else:
        print("'sleeping' canceled")

async def sleeper(m, n, event):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    if n == 3:
        event.set()
    print(f"cycle {m}, step {n}")

async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()
    tasks = []

    for cycle in range(3):
        event.clear()
        # create batch of async tasks to run in parallel
        for step in range(6):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(sleeper(cycle, step, event), name=f"{cycle}_{step}"))

        await interruptable_sleep(2, event)

    # 'join' remaining tasks
    event.set()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    

asyncio.run(main())
```

This pattern sort of "reverses" the idea of a timeout: if a task finishes early, the waiting is canceled . (while timeout means "if a task is too late, cancel it") -

But maybe ou just need the other pattern there: to create a list of all your tasks and call `asyncio.gather`, rather than calling "sleep" to give "time for the other tasks to run".